# Spring state machine builder using StateTransition object

Tags: builder, spring-statemachine

I couldn't find any reference with this functionality. Shall I just implement a helper method in the builder to read fields in StateTransition object and populate the chain configureTransition() call by myself??

Just to confirm not to reinvent the wheels.

UPDATE:
I'm trying to use StateMachineBuilder to configure with some pre-defined states and transitions in a properties file. In Builder, they use this chained call to generate configuration:

builder.configureTransitions().withExternal().source(s1)....

What I have in mind is, everything read from the file is stored in an object, the spring sm library has this StateTransition object. But as far as I know from the API, there is no way to use it directly to configure a state machine. Instead, I can read individual fields in the object and use the chained call above.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand a question, could you elaborate it a little?

Comment: @JanneValkealahti  Thanks. See the updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it like that, what you mentioned is pretty much only option. Hopefully we get a real support for external state machine definition, i.e. tracked in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/78.